# return value from a function inside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have created a module like the following:

```
module.exports = function() {

  function func1 () {

  }

  function func2 () {

  }

  return function() {

    func1();
    func2();

    return value;

  };
}
```

when I call the module in another file

`myModule = require('myModule')`

use the module

`myModule()` I get an undefined value. what do I wrong?

Comment: When I run that code, I get: `func1 () { SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. Try providing a [test case](http://sscce.org/) that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: fixed typos. Now should work

Comment: After the edit, I now get `[Function]` when I run that code (wrapped with `var myModule = require('./myModule.js'); console.log(myModule());`)

Comment: ok this is what I also get

Comment: @Mazzy This is correct and the expected output of the code above. What is  the problem?

Comment: module.exports()() or myModule()() would return "value" (since your module returns a function you need to invoke that function, hence the double parentheses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting a function that when called returns another function which in turn will throw an `ReferenceError` saying that `value` is undefined which you can alleviate by defining `value`.

```
return function() {

    func1();
    func2();

    return 1; //for example

  };
```

In order to run it you need to call it twice.

```
myModule()();
>> 1
```

My guess is that you just want the value returned so wrap it in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
module.exports = function () {
    return (function() {
        func1();
        func2();

        return 1; //for example
    })();
}
```

Comment: Nice comment on what this code does, but not really an answer…

Comment: I think it answers it - since a function is being returned it needs to be invoked to get the return value.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect `myModule()` to return a value you can export IIFE:

```
module.exports = function () {

    function func1() {

    }

    function func2() {

    }

    return function () {
        func1();
        func2();
        return value;
    }();
}
```